# How to use factory_girl for debug data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I use `Rails4`.

### fixtures

I use `fixtures` for **debug data**.
but 
`$ bin/rake db:fixtures:load FIXTURES_PATH=spec/fixtures`
not run `before_validation` and other callbacks.

### factory_girl

I use `factory_girl` for **test**.

like
`$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/foo_spec.rb`.

### seed

I know how to use `factory_girl` in `seed` 
`$ bundle exec rake db:seed`

but I want to use `seed` for *only* **master data**.

### Question

How to use `factory_girl` for **debug data**. and Do I use what command?(`rake ??` or `spec` or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a rake task that uses your factories to create your debug data.  For example, if you had a model (and corresponding factory) named `Report`:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with debug data"
  task :debug_data => :environment do

  puts "Destroy existing data?"
  if STDIN.gets.chomp.upcase == 'Y'
    if Rails.env.production?
      raise "\nI'm sorry, Dave, I can't do that.\n(You're asking me to drop your production database.)"
    end
    Report.destroy_all
  end

  FactoryGirl.create(:report, name: 'Fred')
  FactoryGirl.create(:report, name: 'Barney')
end
```

Place this file in: `lib/tasks/debug_data.rake`
Execute it using: 
`bundle exec rake db:debug_data`